# Not able to build ionic project. Error "CordovaLib:processReleaseResources Failed"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi I am trying to build ionic project with command "cordova build --release android" but getting the error attached with image in full details screenshot.
I have search the error a lot no luck. please help me. thanks

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same Problem and solved it by installing the old Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.3 instead of 24.0.1

Comment: I think the same, actually have updated plus one (24.0.1) build tools after that i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to rename every filename who content a special character (image but also html template, javascript file, css).

For example a greek character in the name of an image.

Comment: I dont think this solution works, because i have one more ionic project that successfully build earlier but now not working. So that running project is also giving the same error. Well will try once!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Its an android build or ionic issue. Downgraded the build version with 23. Don't know exactly where is the issue but 24 and above versions are not working here. Working perfectly with 23.